# Google Play Games Feature Badges not visible at google play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

i integrated Google play services successfully to my android application and added achievements and leader boards, but it's been few days since published but i cant see the badges for it on google play.

Is there anything i have to add to AndroidManifest.xml?

The services are working properly as they should (even on user accounts that are not my list of testers)
And i know that you can see the badges only on google play application from the phone.

Example - World of Goo - has badges
my app - Beat Mania - does not have badges

Answer (score 12, accepted):

just to let everybody know, Leaderboard feature badge appeared after 200 unique users posted their score to leaderboards..

Achievemnts are displayed after 500 users joined leaderboards for this particular game. (maybee it was about how many poeple got an achivement (200 achivements achieved) .. but i can't realy tell)

Comment: I'm just curious, what's your sources?

Comment: This info is based on what I saw in my own aps on google play market

Comment: Curious... I've got 236 players for my main leaderbord in the "Unique players who posted a score to a leaderboard" console column, and still no badge. Do you have more information since then?

Comment: Just wait a bit more, may be they changed the algorithm. I just posted what it was like with my game.

Answer (score 8):

The Google Play Games badges appear automatically on Google Play based on actual feature usage. So you may have to wait for a few days for the badges to appear in your app (provided users are actually using those features. If users are not using those features, you won't get the badging).

Comment: Currently ther are arround 40 users submiting scores to the leaderboard and there are still no badges. But i assume i have not yet reached the limit. Could you specify the exact numbers?