# Leaderboard and achievements badges are not showing on Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play-games, leaderboard, achievements

Some time ago I launched an app that uses Google Play Games Leaderboard and Achievements APIs. From what I've read, both badges should be enabled automatically after a certain threshold (200-300 users).

However, my app now has more than 80K active users using these features, but still no badges on the Google Play page.

So I was thinking... Am I missing something? Did someone manage to enable this badges?

[image: See the screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this [SO posts 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19677439/google-play-games-feature-badges-not-visible-at-google-play), [SO post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118165/google-play-store-my-app-page-does-not-show-the-leaderboard-and-achievements-ic) and [SO post 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994067/why-are-google-play-games-icons-not-shown-in-play-store). Same scenario and same question.

It was said that there is no additional configuration/setup needed to start showing the icons. Also, suggests to wait for a few days to see if the logo will pop up.

Another reason,

> There is a minimum number of players needed to have signed in and been
>   playing your game before the logos will appear. However, Google has
>   not specifically released the number required, although testing shows
>   it is at least 200.

You can also [Contact Google Play support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7100415?hl=en&ref_topic=3364260) to raise your concern about the issue.